# Xamarin iOS app build rejected by Apple due to IPv6

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms, ipv6, appstore-approval

Facing problem with app submission. Beta app is working fine on iPad and iPhone. Also tested app on IPv6 network according to mentioned in following document. App is working fine.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

But apple app review is Rejecting App Again & Again with following reason:
"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.1.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network."

Did the following:
- NSAppTransportSecurity > NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
- Changed HttpClient implementation to NSURSession for Release>iPhone Developer, Automatic:AdHoc & Automatic:AppStore.
- Having valid sever domain name (not static IP).

Do not have idea how to solve it, need help.

Comment: Did you test on an IPv6-only network as Apple does? Apple has instructions on how to configure an IPv6-only network to test.

Comment: If you have used Connectivity plugin, then make sure you used latest version.

Comment: Thank you Ron Maupin for the reply!
Yes I have tested it by creating IPv6 on my mac as mentioned in following documentation.
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

Comment: Hello MilanG, Thanks for the reply. I have used default HttpClient (in System.Net.Http) to fetch data from server (http://). 
App developed & archived through sdk Visual Studio 7.2.2 (build 11) for Mac.
Would you please suggest any additional settings while archiving build for .iOS in Visual Studio